# In MVC web app, delete job is update the view first or delete the data first

Tags: model-view-controller

My app's view is rendered by `model`'s data, each item in data have its view item with a delete button

when the use want delete this data item, he would click the delete the button, here come the problem, I have two choice:

- delete the view immediately, then delete the real data in asynchronous job.But if the delete in back-end failed?
- Not delete the view immediately, delete the data in back-end, when delete the data success, put the delete view function in the callback, but I think this could influence the use exprience, this delete job should be sync or async?

so which solution is better? Why?

Answer (score 0):

If the delete doesn't take a lot of time I would just have the user wait for confirmation. This is mostly for simplicity's sake.

You could simply resume 'as if it happened' and only do a form of callback in case of failures.

After giving the delete command the user's next operation may require that the object is actually deleted. E.g. creating a new object under the same name or wanting to manipulate another object in such a way that it requires the other object to no longer be there.

In other words; if it's async the user may need to be aware it is.